# How to add two buttons instead to two actionlinks in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a two button which when clicked calls two different actions. I have used `Html.BeginForm` to create one button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("someAction", "someController"))
{
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

How do I add a second button without actually nesting two forms? Is there some other way? Kindly help!

This is my code:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditEmployee", new { id = item.EmployeeID }) |
               @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmployee", new { id = item.EmployeeID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Html.BeginForm is not for creating buttons. It is to create a form tag. If you want another button which submits the form to a second action method, why not add a form below your current form (not nested) ?

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. You want to replace the link with a button ? Then do it. What is stopping you

Comment: use Bootstrap to style the links as buttons...

Comment: I got this fixed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting indentation issues with the buttons while using two form one below the other. I got this fixed without using any form tag. Here is my answer:

```
<td>
    <a href="@Url.Action("EditEmployee", "Employee", new {id = item.EmployeeID})" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
        Edit
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteEmployee", "Employee", new { id = item.EmployeeID })" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the record with employee name @item.UserName')">
        Delete
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```